# gerrit replication configuration:Cannot replicate because of reject HostKey:slave.gerrit.server

Tags: replication, gerrit

i'm doing gerrit replication configuration,but encounter the following issue in log/replication_log on gerrit master server xx.xx.xx.64:

> Cannot replicate to ssh://gerrit@xx.xx.xx.48/home/gerrit/gerrit_site/git/All-Users.git
> org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://gerrit@xx.xx.xx.48/home/gerrit/gerrit_site/git/All-Users.git: reject HostKey: xx.xx.xx.48

the configuration file on gerrit master server xx.xx.xx.64:

1. ~/.ssh/config:
   `Host xx.xx.xx.48`
   `User gerrit`
   `Hostname xx.xx.xx.48`
   `IdentityFile /home/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa`
   `PreferredAuthentications publickey`
   `StrictHostKeyChecking no`
   `UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null`
2. has execute the cmd: **sudo su -c 'ssh xx.xx.xx.48 echo' gerrit**, to update `known_hosts` file
3. and generate ssh keys with PEM format, using the cmd **sh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"**
4. and the replication.config is as follows:
   `[remote "slave_48"]`
   `url = ssh://gerrit@xx.xx.xx.48:/home/gerrit/gerrit_site/git/${name}.git`
   `replicateProjectDeletions = true`
   `mirror = true`
   `replicationDelay = 1`
5. and i'm sure that gerrit master server xx.xx.xx.64 can directly connect to remote slaver xx.xx.xx.48 without entering the password by cmd **ssh gerrit@xx.xx.xx.48**

how can i continue to debug?